# How can I kill all sessions connecting to my oracle database?

Tags: oracle, session, sqlplus, kill, database-administration

I need to quickly (and forcibly) kill off all external sessions connecting to my oracle database without the supervision of and administrator.

I don't want to just lock the database and let the users quit gracefully.

How would I script this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This answer is heavily influenced by a conversation here:  http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1395151&page=3

```
ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;

begin     
    for x in (  
            select Sid, Serial#, machine, program  
            from v$session  
            where  
                machine <> 'MyDatabaseServerName'  
        ) loop  
        execute immediate 'Alter System Kill Session '''|| x.Sid  
                     || ',' || x.Serial# || ''' IMMEDIATE';  
    end loop;  
end;
```

I skip killing sessions originating on the database server to avoid killing off Oracle's connections to itself.

Comment: I get ORA-06550. ALTER SYSTEM seems not allowed inside begin end

Answer (score 12):

As SYS:

```
startup force;
```

Brutal, yet elegant.

Answer (score 7):

Before killing sessions, if possible do

```
ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;
```

to stop new sessions from connecting.

Comment: Yes indeed, this does make my solution more complete.

Comment: Important! Do not forget to disable the restricted mode before disconnect

Answer (score 5):

I've been using something like this for a while to kill my sessions on a shared server. The first line of the 'where' can be removed to kill all non 'sys' sessions:

```
BEGIN
  FOR c IN (
      SELECT s.sid, s.serial#
      FROM v$session s
      WHERE (s.Osuser = 'MyUser' or s.MACHINE = 'MyNtDomain\MyMachineName')
      AND s.USERNAME <> 'SYS'
      AND s.STATUS <> 'KILLED'
  )
  LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter system kill session ''' || c.sid || ',' || c.serial# || '''';
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stop new users from connecting, but allow current sessions to continue until they are inactive, you can put the database in QUIESCE mode:

```
ALTER SYSTEM QUIESCE RESTRICTED;
```

From the [Oracle Database Administrator's Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/start004.htm):

> Non-DBA active sessions will continue
>   until they become inactive. An active
>   session is one that is currently
>   inside of a transaction, a query, a
>   fetch, or a PL/SQL statement; or a
>   session that is currently holding any
>   shared resources (for example,
>   enqueues). No inactive sessions are
>   allowed to become active...Once all
>   non-DBA sessions become inactive, the
>   ALTER SYSTEM QUIESCE RESTRICTED
>   statement completes, and the database
>   is in a quiesced state

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. In my case I wanted to boot the users off without waiting for their transactions to finish (some of them are rather long). Everybody out of the pool NOW!!!

Answer (score 2):

Additional info

> Important Oracle 11g changes to alter session kill session
>
> Oracle author Mladen Gogala notes that an @ sign is now required to
>   kill a session when using the inst_id column:

```
alter system kill session '130,620,@1';
```

http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_killing_oracle_sessions.htm

Answer (score 1):

**Try trigger on logon**

Insted of trying disconnect users you should not allow them to connect.

There is and example of such trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER rds_logon_trigger
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
BEGIN
  IF SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') not in ('192.168.2.121','192.168.2.123','192.168.2.233') THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003,'You are not allowed to connect to the database');
  END IF;

  IF (to_number(to_char(sysdate,'HH24'))< 6) and (to_number(to_char(sysdate,'HH24')) >18) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20005,'Logon only allowed during business hours');
  END IF;

END;
```

Comment: This would indeed work if my goal was to limit access to specific IP ranges or times. My goal was to force all my users off to database, not prevent logins. Thanks, though - I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I found the below snippet helpful.  Taken from:  http://jeromeblog-jerome.blogspot.com/2007/10/how-to-unlock-record-on-oracle.html

```
select
owner||'.'||object_name obj ,
oracle_username||' ('||s.status||')' oruser ,
os_user_name osuser ,
machine computer ,
l.process unix ,
s.sid||','||s.serial# ss ,
r.name rs ,
to_char(s.logon_time,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') time
from v$locked_object l ,
dba_objects o ,
v$session s ,
v$transaction t ,
v$rollname r
where l.object_id = o.object_id
and s.sid=l.session_id
and s.taddr=t.addr
and t.xidusn=r.usn
order by osuser, ss, obj
;
```

Then ran:

```
Alter System Kill Session '<value from ss above>'
;
```

To kill individual sessions.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question asked,
here is the most accurate SQL to accomplish the job,
you can combine it with PL/SQL loop to actually run kill statements:

```
select ses.USERNAME,
    substr(MACHINE,1,10) as MACHINE, 
    substr(module,1,25) as module,
    status, 
    'alter system kill session '''||SID||','||ses.SERIAL#||''';' as kill
from v$session ses LEFT OUTER JOIN v$process p ON (ses.paddr=p.addr)
where schemaname <> 'SYS'
    and not exists
    (select 1 
        from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS 
        where GRANTED_ROLE='DBA' 
            and schemaname=grantee)
    and machine!='yourlocalhostname' 
order by LAST_CALL_ET desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

If Oracle is running in Unix /Linux then we can grep for all client connections and kill it

grep all oracle client process:

ps -ef | grep LOCAL=NO | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | wc -l

Kill all oracle client process :

kill -9 `ps -ef | grep LOCAL=NO | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`