# Dropping Oracle connections using a query

Tags: oracle

I wanted to drop/kill connections made to specific schema of a database. Could you please sugest a prudent way to do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to prevent a user from connecting you could lock the account:

```
ALTER USER usr ACCOUNT LOCK;
```

If you want to disconnect all sessions of a user, you could use the [method described in another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342/how-can-i-kill-all-sessions-connecting-to-my-oracle-database):

```
BEGIN
   FOR x IN (SELECT Sid, Serial# FROM v$session WHERE username = 'USR') LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Alter System Kill Session ''' || x.Sid || ',' 
                        || x.Serial# || ''' IMMEDIATE';
   END LOOP;
END;
```