# Hibernate - Getting exception : maximum number of processes (550) exceeded

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jdbc, database-connection

I am using hibernate 3 along with spring.My Hibernate configurations are as under :

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect
hibernate.connection.release_mode=on_close
```

But after starting application, even if only one user accesses it then also I am getting this exception :

```
ORA-00020: maximum number of processes (550) exceeded
```

This is stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00020: maximum number of processes (550) exceeded

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:799)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1038)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:839)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3329)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2037)
```

I have kept connection pool time out = 5000. I have also tried to found the cause and got that release mode may affect the mechanism of closing DB resources. But I couldn't find exact solution for that.
Please help..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a *database* error not an application error so you need to go to the database to solve it. 550 processes is a lot more than it sounds so either someone has gone insane or you have a lot of inactive processes running.

The best way to find out is to query the [`v$session`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_3016.htm#REFRN30223) view or `Gv$session` if you're using a RAC, look at the `STATUS` column.

Take careful not of where all these sessions are coming from; the `OSUSER`, `TERMINAL` and `PROGRAM` will probably be the most useful. It might almost be worth creating a temporary table with this information - proof and a record afterwards. Then after checking that you're not going to break anything, and with your DBAs if you have any, kill all the inactive sessions [simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342/how-can-i-kill-all-sessions-connecting-to-my-oracle-database) or [one at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545560/how-to-kill-a-running-select-statement).

That'll remove the error but if it's occurred once it can occur again, so you need to solve it. Either:

- You've got a lot of people using the database.
- There is an application / program somewhere that is not closing it's
  sessions after it's finished.
- Someone is connecting in the middle of a loop.

Whichever reason it is you need to track it down and correct it. I'd start with the program or terminal from `v$session` that had the most number of processes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I will surely check what u suggested..
But I want to figure out 1 thing about the three causes you pointed out, that first one is not possible since even if only 1 person using app then also these error occurs.2nd and 3rd points are worth taking care. thanks again..!

Comment: @adn_295, just because you're the only person using the app doesn't mean you're the only person using the database. What if someone has connected using a different method?

Comment: OK, got your point..!! however very less possibility seems for this but still i will chk out