# How to kill own Oracle SQL sessions without DBA privileges?

Tags: sql, r, oracle, jdbc, database-administration

Is there a way for a user to terminate one's own session/connections, given an Oracle SID, without DBA rights?

Specifically, I can run this in my DB without admin rights:

```
SELECT SID, "SERIAL#", STATUS, USERNAME
 FROM V$SESSION
 WHERE 
 (USERNAME = 'LastF') 
 AND
 (STATUS = 'INACTIVE');
```

But when I go to kill my orphaned session (from another session to which I still have access),

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION "12, 123"
```

I get the following:

```
JDBC ERROR: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Note: I am connecting with JDBC through R/Rstudio using the RJDBC package.

#### Motivation:

It doesn't appear too difficult to kill sessions in Oracle SQL:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/manproc008.htm#ADMIN11192
[How can I kill all sessions connecting to my oracle database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342/how-can-i-kill-all-sessions-connecting-to-my-oracle-database)

However, for non-DBA users who have orphaned connections (i.e. internet outage, 3rd party client that manages connections errors out, etc), it can be really frustrating to get:

```
ORA-02391 exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit
```

and have to wait for timeout.

Comment: Good article about doing this here http://dba-oracle.com/t_granting_alter_system_kill_session.htm but in a nutshell either get DBA's to write a procedure that will kill sessions (with appropriate safegaurds) and grant execute on that procedure OR get them to grant ALTER SESSION (I have this on all dev databases, will certainly NOT be granted on PROD)

Comment: @ShaunPeterson - I assume you meant ALTER **SYSTEM**? ALTER *SESSION* has nothing to do with killing sessions.

Comment: @mathguy yes you are correct thank you for picking that up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To successfully run an `ALTER SYSTEM` command, you don't need to be the DBA, but you **do** need the `ALTER SYSTEM` privilege to be granted to you (or to the "user" owning the application through which you connect to the database - which may be different from "you" as the "user" of RStudio).

You have a few options:

- ask the DBA to kill the session
- ask to be granted the `ALTER SYSTEM` privilege (which is a very poor practice)
- have a "supervisor" (however defined - responsible specifically for these situations) be granted the `ALTER SYSTEM` privilege, who will be in charge of killing such sessions
- (perhaps the best option) create a packaged
  procedure whose only task is to kill orphaned sessions. Grant `ALTER SYSTEM` to the package owner, and grant execute privilege on that
  package to individual users (as needed). The procedure should be
  written to only kill specific kinds of sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to cancel whatever is running in the session

```
    DECLARE
      l_status  v$session.status%TYPE;
    BEGIN

      dbms_system.set_ev( &sid, &serial, 10237, 1, '');

      LOOP
        SELECT status INTO l_status FROM v$session
          WHERE sid = &sid and serial# = &serial;
        EXIT WHEN l_status='INACTIVE';
      END LOOP;

      dbms_system.set_ev( &sid, &serial, 10237, 0, '');
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to create a direct select grant on sys.v_$session

grant select on v_$session to

Where  is the schema that owns the above procedure. This has to be a direct grant and not through a role.

Check the [link](http://dba-oracle.com/t_granting_alter_system_kill_session.htm) for more details and given by Donald Burleson

Answer (score 0):

we can kill the oracle session with pid ,
if you are unable to identify the operating system process identifier (spid) from the query , you can issue the following query to help identify the correct session:

```
SELECT s.sid, s.serial#, p.spid
FROM v$process p, v$session s
WHERE p.addr = s.paddr
AND s.username = '<username>';
```

At the operating system prompt, issue the kill command and supply the operating system process identifier (spid):

```
kill <spid>
```